# where to look for (live or recorded) air traffic conversations for a specific area?

Tags: united-states, software-defined-radio, airband

I am wondering if there's any chance to get a short fragment of ATC/pilot radio exchange of any flight to/from small airport of Talkeetna (Alaska). This airport seems to be not present on [liveatc.net](http://liveatc.net), and I just don't know any other web resources of that kind. I imagine that there might be some local amateurs streaming (I do know the frequency: 123.6 MHz) but I don't even know where to search for that kind of things - some local forums, etc? I googled and found some websites, for example [GlobalTuners](https://www.globaltuners.com/receiver/list.php) (doesn't have what I need), [RemoteHams](http://www.remotehams.com/) (requires callsign which I don't have) - any other suggestions?

P.S. why I need this: I'm making a small video (non-commercial of course, only for friends) about our recent Denali expedition, including the footage of our flights from Talkeetna to the basecamp and back. Intensive radio exchange during the whole flight made an authentic background but unfortunately I could not record it as it was only audible in the headphones. So it would be cool to find a sound track replacement.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly a good fit for this site. It doesn't relate to amateur radio or the technology of radio

Comment: ok, maybe you're right. I'll keep the post for a while and delete it if there will be any other downvote or similar comment.

Comment: Vasily, this question is probably on-topic at https://aviation.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this site which might be helpful: https://www.adsbexchange.com/

Comment: @VasilyA Glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

126.3 MHz is the Talkeetna CTAF (Common Traffic Advisory Frequency). You may have heard some traffic on this frequency while in-flight. Pilots use this to advise other pilots that they are in the area of Talkeetna  since their is no ATC (Air Traffic Control) facility at the airport. You will likely not find a monitoring site for this frequency.

You may find some suitable recordings  or an Internet listening station of the Anchorage ARTCC (Air Route Traffic Control Center) as they handle all   APCH/DEP (Approach and Departure) for Talkeetna on 125.55/254.3.  It may take some listening before hearing a Talkeetna related exchange, however.